# ETL datetime to integer error code

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, etl, sqldatatypes

I'm writing an ETL in visual studio 2017 and I am getting this error: 
[image: Error Message]

So, I can't convert datetime datatype to integer datatype.

But the problem is, my query returns an int and not a datetime datatype.
Query:

```
SELECT    e.eventName, e.eventType, e.numberOfPersons, 
          (SELECT timeKey FROM StarSchema.dbo.timeDim WHERE (r.reservationDate = [DATE])) AS reservationDate,
          (SELECT timeKey FROM StarSchema.dbo.timeDim AS timeDim_2 WHERE (e.eventStartDate = [DATE])) AS eventStartDate,
          (SELECT timeKey FROM StarSchema.dbo.timeDim AS timeDim_1 WHERE (e.eventEndDate = [DATE])) AS eventEndDate,
          contact.name, customer.company, invoices.price, invoices.invoiceId
FROM      events AS e 
          INNER JOIN reservation AS r ON e.reservationId = r.reservationId 
          INNER JOIN customer ON e.customerId = customer.customerId 
          INNER JOIN contact ON customer.contactId = contact.contactId 
          INNER JOIN invoices ON e.invoiceId = invoices.invoiceId
```

This is the result when I run this query: [image: Result]
The reservationDate, eventStartDate and eventEndDate reference a key in my time dimension, as an int not a datetime.

I tried creating a view with this query and then using it in my ETL but Visual studio still processed the columns as the datetime datatype.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: So to be clear,, my goal is to have the datatype return as an INT and not a date datatype. I need the INT to reference my time dimension.

Comment: Dates aren't integers. This means that either you used the wrong type in the ETL or you created the dataflow task and then *changed* the query to return an integer key instead of the actual date. Why don't you use the *date* as a date dimension key anyway? It only takes 3 bytes

Comment: Furthermore, dimensions are meant to be used in the `FROM` clause, not in subselects. Why don't you use the dimensions in the FROM clause.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Thanks for your response! I am creating a starschema following Kimball's literature, the book says that I should create surrogate keys for my date dimension. Now when I think about it, I don't see any technical arguments for why I should do this. 
I use the dimension in my subselect because it's a triple reference. With 1 reference in the FROM clause I get duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with a CAST as DATE on the inside:

```
SELECT    e.eventName, e.eventType, e.numberOfPersons, 
          (SELECT CAST (timeKey AS DATE) FROM ArenAStar.dbo.timeDim WHERE 
          (r.reservationDate = [DATE])) AS reservationDate,
      (SELECT CAST (timeKey AS DATE) FROM ArenAStar.dbo.timeDim AS timeDim_2 
WHERE 
      (e.eventStartDate = [DATE])) AS eventStartDate,
      (SELECT timeKey FROM ArenAStar.dbo.timeDim AS timeDim_1 WHERE 
      (e.eventEndDate = [DATE])) AS eventEndDate,
      contact.name, customer.company, invoices.price, invoices.invoiceId
FROM  events AS e 
      INNER JOIN reservation AS r ON e.reservationId = r.reservationId 
      INNER JOIN customer ON e.customerId = customer.customerId 
      INNER JOIN contact ON customer.contactId = contact.contactId 
      INNER JOIN invoices ON e.invoiceId = invoices.invoiceId
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helped me solve my issue. I placed CAST around the subquerys, so CAST (( SELECT ........ ) AS INT) AS reservationDate,.